# How do i create a brother predicate for prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I have been told to create a brother predicate which finds out if a brother has a sibling. `Brother(B, S) :-`. I know that you would need to find out if they have the same parents but i am not sure how to do this.

```
father(dan,phil).
father(dan,jack).
father(dan,christine).
father(phil,kenton).
father(phil,shula).
father(phil,david).
father(phil,elizabeth).
father(jack,lillian).
father(jack,tony).
father(jack,jenny).
father(tony,tommy).
father(tony,helen).
father(tony,john).
father(roger,adam).
father(roger,debbie).
father(brian,kate).
father(david,pip).
father(david,josh).
father(mark,daniel).

mother(doris,phil).
mother(doris,jack).
mother(doris,christine).
mother(jill,kenton).
mother(jill,shula).
mother(jill,david).
mother(jill,elizabeth).
mother(peggy,lillian).
mother(peggy,tony).
mother(peggy,jenny).
mother(pat,tommy).
mother(pat,helen).
mother(pat,john).
mother(jenny,adam).
mother(jenny,debbie).
mother(jenny,kate).
mother(ruth,pip).
mother(ruth,josh).
mother(shula,daniel).

male(dan).
male(phil).
male(jack).
male(kenton).
male(david).
male(tony).
male(brian).
male(roger).
male(mark).
male(john).
male(tommy).
male(adam).
male(daniel).
male(josh).

female(doris).
female(jill).
female(peggy).
female(christine).
female(shula).
female(ruth).
female(elizabeth).
female(lillian).
female(pat).
female(jenny).
female(helen).
female(debbie).
female(kate).
female(pip).

dead(dan).
dead(doris).
dead(jack).
dead(mark).
dead(john).
dead(fred).


parent(X,Y) :-
        father(X,Y); mother(X,Y).

grandfather(X,Y) :-
        father(X,Z), mother(Z,Y).
grandfather(X,Y) :-
        father(X,Z), father(Z,Y).

ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).

archer(dan).
archer(X) :- father(P,X), archer(P).
```

This is the document i have which defines parents, grandfather etc. 
I need to create a brother predicate which sits as brother(B being brother, S being sibling). For example brother(liam, georgia). Liam is the brother of Georgia should be true

Comment: You need to write the Prolog that expresses the relationship of brother in terms of the basic facts. It's a little unclear exactly what your facts are (since you mention parent, mother, father, etc, but no specifics), but if you have parent, then in terms of parent: *`B` is a brother of `S` **if** `B` has a parent `X`, and `X` is a parent of `S`*. If this is confusing, you may need to go through a basic Prolog tutorial. As a similar example, if you said, *`F` is a banana **if** `F` is a fruit, and `F` is yellow.*, that could be expressed as: `is_banana(F) :- is_fruit(F), color(F, yellow).`

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure if you searched stackoverflow.com for `[prolog] brother` you'd probably find some similar questions that will help.

Comment: You don't say which other predicates are available? `parent/2`? `child/2`, `male/2` and `female/2`? With what can we work?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have updated my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve your problem by first providing a formal definition of what a `brother(B,S)` is:

> A brother `B` of a *slibing* `S` **is a `male/1`** which has **the
>   same `father/2` `F` and `mother/2`** `M`.

Now that we know this, we write for each condition one or more lines.

---

The first one is simply the head of the clause:

```
brother(B,S) :-
```

---

Now since a brother is a `male/1`, the first condition we check is:

```
    male(B),
```

---

Next we have to check whether they have the same `father/2`. Therefore we define a father `F`, and `F` has to be the father of `B`, so we write:

```
    father(F,B),
```

since that father has to be the father of `S` as well, we write:

```
    father(F,S),
```

---

The same holds for the `mother`: we define a mother `M` and check that this mother is the mother of both `B` and `S`:

```
    mother(M,B),
    mother(M,S).
```

---

Now putting it all together we obtain:

```
brother(B,S) :-
    male(B),
    father(F,B),
    father(F,S),
    mother(M,B),
    mother(M,S).
```

Now a problem is that with this predicate, a male person will be a brother of himself. If you do not want this behavior, we add a constraint:

> And a person is not a `brother/2` of himself.

You thus have to use the *not equal* predicate:

```
    B \= S.
```

Or the full predicate:

```
brother(B,S) :-
    male(B),
    father(F,B),
    father(F,S),
    mother(M,B),
    mother(M,S),
    B \= S.
```

This predicate generates the following answers:

```
?- brother(B,S).
B = phil,
S = jack ;
B = phil,
S = christine ;
B = jack,
S = phil ;
B = jack,
S = christine ;
B = kenton,
S = shula ;
B = kenton,
S = david ;
B = kenton,
S = elizabeth ;
B = david,
S = kenton
...
```

Comment: Are you allowed to place new elements like father(F,B)? cause it has not been used before

Comment: Wasnt sure you were able to but it works so you clearly are able to. Thanks for the help. i have ticked as the best solution :)